# why the app cant be opened when no errors are thrown?

Tags: android, crash, android-jetpack-compose

edit:

im new to android app developing and im building a simple app to capture an image (later on i want to manipulate the image and use some ML models for classification task).
Im having a problem with showing the preview of the image (still in the beginning of the development). i followed the android developer guide to cameraX and some other help with the errors i had from stackoverflow's furom. currently im not having any errors thrown but when i run the app (locally on android studio and when i deploy it to my device) all it shows is a green screen and not the camera preview.

This is the code

```
package com.example.try_again

import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
import android.widget.LinearLayout
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.camera.core.AspectRatio.RATIO_16_9
import androidx.camera.core.CameraSelector
import androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.wrapContentSize
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.res.stringResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.camera.core.Preview as Preview_2
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView
import com.example.try_again.ui.theme.TryagainTheme

import androidx.camera.lifecycle.ProcessCameraProvider
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.LocalLifecycleOwner
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    private lateinit var cameraProviderFuture : ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        cameraProviderFuture = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this)

        setContent {
            TryagainTheme {
                MainFun(cameraProviderFuture)
            }
        }
    }

}

fun bindPreview(
    cameraProvider: ProcessCameraProvider?,
    lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner?,
    previewView: PreviewView?,
) {
    if (cameraProvider != null && lifecycleOwner != null && previewView != null) {
        val preview: Preview_2 = Preview_2.Builder()
            .setTargetAspectRatio(RATIO_16_9)
            .build()

        val cameraSelector: CameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
            .requireLensFacing(CameraSelector.LENS_FACING_BACK)
            .build()

        preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.surfaceProvider)

        var camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainFun(cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>) {
    PreviewFun(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxSize()
        .wrapContentSize(Alignment.Center), cameraProviderFuture
    )
}

@Composable
fun PreviewFun(modifier: Modifier = Modifier, cameraProviderFuture: ListenableFuture<ProcessCameraProvider>) {

    Column(
        modifier = modifier,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally)

    {

        val lifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current
        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                PreviewView(context).apply {
                    setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN)
                    layoutParams = LinearLayout.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT)
                    scaleType = PreviewView.ScaleType.FILL_START
                    implementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.COMPATIBLE
                    post {
                        cameraProviderFuture.addListener(Runnable {
                            val cameraProvider = cameraProviderFuture.get()
                            bindPreview(
                                cameraProvider,
                                lifecycleOwner,
                                this,
                            )
                        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context))
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        Button(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.capture))

        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate any help guys.

Tried to build an app to capture and preview an image. app only shows green screen and not the camera preview.

Comment: Check logcat on Android studio.